# How can i set up VS Code Ubuntu clang?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, clang

I am trying to setup vs code with clang compiler. I installed the compiler via the Ubuntu terminal. Now I'm trying to run my first application, but I get the following error: "Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebugger is invalid. What needs to be done?

Comment: Please provide more information about the error like if you're using any extension for C/C++ or not and your `launch.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using C C++ and Code runnner ext.
Here is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).